# ScaleTransform within a canvas: Centering around mouse pointer causing issues

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, scaletransform

I have a canvas (OuterCanvas) within a canvas (InnerCanvas) and am handling zooming in an out as follows:

```
private ScaleTransform ScaleTransform = new ScaleTransform();

private void OuterCanvas_MouseWheel(Object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Delta >= 1)
    {
        ScaleTransform.ScaleX += 0.03;
        ScaleTransform.ScaleY += 0.03;
    }
    else
    {
        ScaleTransform.ScaleX -= 0.03;
        ScaleTransform.ScaleY -= 0.03;
    }
    ScaleTransform.CenterX = ActualWidth / 2;
    ScaleTransform.CenterY = ActualHeight / 2;
    InnerCanvas.RenderTransform = TransformGroup;
}
```

This zooms in and out quite okay at the centre of the canvas. I'd like to zoom in and out around the mouse pointer, so change the `CenterX` and `CenterY` lines as follows:

```
ScaleTransform.CenterX = e.GetPosition(this).X;
ScaleTransform.CenterY = e.GetPosition(this).Y;
```

Again this works satisfactory, however if I attempt to move the mouse during two zoom events (mouse wheel events), the whole canvas jumps rather drastically as the scale factor increases or decreases.

[Demonstration of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HGBe.gif)

This is the same issue as when the `CenterX` and `CenterY` properties are set to the `ActualWidth/2` and `ActualHeight/2` and the window size is changed.

What should the correct handling be of the `CenterX` and `CenterY` properties be to avoid this issue?

Comment: One way to solve this would be to do an animation that smoothly changes over time.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I do plan to add animation but I'd rather address the underlying issue rather than making an incorrect transition look smooth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a more or less complete solution, including the possibility to pan the inner Canvas:

```
<Canvas x:Name="outerCanvas"
        MouseWheel="OnMouseWheel"
        MouseMove="OnMouseMove"
        MouseLeftButtonDown="OnMouseLeftButtonDown"
        MouseLeftButtonUp="OnMouseLeftButtonUp">
    <Canvas x:Name="innerCanvas"
            Width="400" Height="400" Background="AliceBlue">
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <MatrixTransform />
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

with these event handlers:

```
private double zoomScaleFactor = 1.1;
private Point? mousePos;

private void OnMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var pos = e.GetPosition(outerCanvas);
    var scale = e.Delta > 0 ? zoomScaleFactor : 1 / zoomScaleFactor;
    var transform = (MatrixTransform)innerCanvas.RenderTransform;
    var matrix = transform.Matrix;
    matrix.ScaleAt(scale, scale, pos.X, pos.Y);
    transform.Matrix = matrix;
}

private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (mousePos.HasValue)
    {
        var pos = e.GetPosition(outerCanvas);
        var delta = pos - mousePos.Value;
        var transform = (MatrixTransform)innerCanvas.RenderTransform;
        var matrix = transform.Matrix;
        matrix.Translate(delta.X, delta.Y);
        transform.Matrix = matrix;
        mousePos = pos;
    }
}

private void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (outerCanvas.CaptureMouse())
    {
        mousePos = e.GetPosition(outerCanvas);
    }
}

private void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    outerCanvas.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    mousePos = null;
}
```

Comment: Perfect - that was exactly what I was aiming for, but for the sake of the question stripped out the panning.